# New Line in Data attribute

Tags: html, newline, custom-data-attribute

How do I insert a new line into a data-* attribute? I have read articles/responses saying escape sequences, but none have worked.

Let's say I have a button tag and when clicked I want to pass data to a javascript method and display a dynamic popup modal.

```
<button id="myButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="myModal" data-info="Some content. This content is on a new line"
```

Data-info will get pushed to a div in the modal. What needs to go between the two sentences to display them on separate lines. (Essentially a 
 within the data-info attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do an array on *data-info* with differents text you need.

Next create *p* elements inner the modal window or other you want with te information of the *data-info*

```
<button id="myButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="myModal" data-info='{"text1":"Hello world","text2":"Bye world"}'>
Hello</button>

$( "#myButton" ).click(function() {
  $("#content").append($("<p></p>").text($("#myButton").data("info").text1));
  $("#content").append($("<p></p>").text($("#myButton").data("info").text2));
});
```

Here and example: https://jsfiddle.net/hectoruch/bfx0Lnvv/